# New to ConTeXt, looking for better manual than PRAGMA

Tags: context, documentation

I am an experienced user of LaTeX learning ConTeXt. However, I find the manuals on the PRAGMA website to be less than ideal. Does anyone have a suggestion for a manual or text?

Comment: The main documentation is [on the wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net). If you have trouble with
 manuals at the [Pragma site](http://www.pragma-ade.com/document-1.htm) you are invited to post suggestions for improvement on [the mailing list](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Mailing_Lists#Mailing_lists).

Comment: @phg Would you like to make it an answer?